# Putting JPanel on JFrame of any use?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

I am working in the NetBeans. For that when I am working in the new `JFrame` form or the design view if I add the panel and then add the label and rest of the contents, it makes no difference if I don't add a panel and add the contents like `JLabel`, `JButton`, etc. it makes no difference.

Is there any reason why panel should be added to the frame? I tried to close the application when the panel was inserted and when it was not inserted on the frame, the application closes both the times. (When I press run and try to close the application, both times it closes.)

Then what is the use of putting `JPanel` on a `JFrame`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add components to the frame the components are added to the content pane of the frame which by default is a JPanel. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Top Level Containers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) for more information.

By creating a separate panel and adding components to that panel you give yourself more flexibility when designing your application. For example you may want to use a `CardLayout` which allows you to swap out different panels on the frame. The tutorial also has a section on using CardLayout.